# Is it possible to use vim's clientserver functionality to keep settings synchronized?

Tags: vimrc, clientserver

I usually have multiple instances of vim running on the same machine. When I make a change to my vimrc I can just `:source ~/.vimrc` (with an easy mapping or an autocmd). But in order to have all running instances reflect the change I have to run that in each of them separately. Can I use the `clientserver` feature to tell all instances to reload my vimrc?

I would also be interested in solutions that don't use `clientserver`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can tell a Vim server to reload the vimrc file like so:

```
$ vim --servername MARTIN --remote-send '<Esc>:source $MYVIMRC<CR>'
```

And you can get a list of all servers with:

```
$ vim --serverlist
MARTIN
CARPETSMOKER
```

Which can be combined with a `for` loop:

```
$ for s in $(vim --serverlist); do vim --servername "$s" --remote-send '<Esc>:source $MYVIMRC<CR>'; done
```

Since that's a lot of typing, you could put it in a shell script in `~/bin/reload-vimrc`; you can of course also call it from within Vim:

```
:!reload-vimrc
```

If you're running Linux, and want to get really crazy, you could use [`inotifywatch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch) from [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools) to monitor your vimrc file(s) for changes, and execute this automatically on every change (untested, example adapted from manpage)

```
$ inotifywatch -v -e modify -t 60 -r ~/.vimrc ~/.vim
```

I wouldn't recommend this, though ... If you accidentally save a file with a
syntax error you could bork all your vim session...

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about clientserver, but since you said you were interested in other solutions I would recommend looking into this writeup about dotfiles from Github.

https://dotfiles.github.io

You obviously don't have to use Github, but the concepts are sound and seem to be widely used.

Comment: While I do think having your dotfiles under version control is awesome, I was specifically asking about instances of vim running on the same machine (I've updated the question).

Comment: -1; This answer doesn't really have any bearing on the asked question. The question is about *reloading vimrc*, not *managing vimrc*.

Comment: The original question prior to my answer did not make it clear he was talking about instances on the same machine. At the time my answer did address the question.